# Gradient of function partitioned

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

I have a function that can be thought of as follows
$$
f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)
$$
I want to take the gradient with respect to the full input $z = (x, y)$. How do I do this?
$$
\nabla_z f(z) = \nabla_{x,y} f(x,y) = \nabla_{x,y} g(x) + \nabla_{x,y} h(y) = ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of gradient $\nabla f(x,y) = (\partial_xf(x,y),\partial_yf(x,y))$.
In your case $\partial_x f(x,y) = g'(x)$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = h'(y)$ so
$$\nabla f(x,y) = (g'(x),h'(y))$$